# Problem in make a voice recorder by record.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a voice recorder for my website that starts recording automatically on page load, stops after a time I define in code and uploads the the file to the server.

I've struggled with record.js to find out. I had found bugs when I tested in wamp but when I uploaded files in a server, the code didn't work anymore.

I don't know what to do...

here's the code on my sever:

www.hozooronline.ir/2
www.hozooronline.ir/3

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Show what you tried and where it failed (or even better, provide a minimal example that reproduces the failure), and not a link to your code. Please visit the tour to learn more about Stack Overflow: stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: please provide us some sample you are working with

Comment: i visit your site the problem is that you are serving your site with HTTP protocol which is not secure that's why browser don't allow you to access mike. i.e any media device is not accessible through HTTP protocol.